# openssl bad decrypt error using gcm mode

Tags: encryption, openssl, google-cloud-messaging

Using openssl-1.0.1g command line for simple file encryption/decryption, when I issue the commands

openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -k secret -in file.txt -out file.ssl
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -k secret -in file.ssl

The contents of file.txt go to stdout as expected.  However, when I issue the commands

openssl enc -aes-256-gcm -k secret -in file.txt -out file.ssl
openssl enc -d -aes-256-gcm -k secret -in file.ssl

The contents of file.txt go to stdout but the string "bad decrypt" goes to stderr.

Am I missing something or is there a bug in the openssl gcm implementation?

I have tried substituting "-pass pass:secret" for "-k secret" and get the same results.

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: For the benefit of others who land here: [OpenSSL User List: v1.0.1g command line gcm error](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mailing.openssl.users/hGggWxfrZbA/unBfGlsfXyoJ).

Comment: Your question triggered a documentation patch. Matt Caswell committed it today. [Add information to BUGS section of enc documentation. PR#3354](https://git.openssl.org/gitweb/?p=openssl.git;a=blobdiff;f=doc/apps/enc.pod;h=629611d137fd77214999bdd7528c199909a62758;hp=3dee4ed9923848514b887184b78a100417241f4a;hb=18c4f522f49eb54a61bada6d39a8b137b6751f01;hpb=ab6577a46ecee670b640f0ee49e2ebef80ad18a7).